# Can I trigger a proactive message in Bot Framework Emulator only by notify endpoint?

Tags: python, botframework, proactive, botframeworkemulator

I am trying to build a simple Microsoft Bot Framework v4 bot with Python that will send me a proactive message using the Bot Framework Emulator. For example, when a deadline for submitting a work is less than a day.
I had a look in the documentation and found the following sentence: "The application logic for initiating a proactive message is outside the scope of the SDK. For this sample, a notify endpoint, in addition to a standard messages endpoint, is used to trigger the proactive turn.".
Does this mean I need to define a method that triggers the notify endpoint to send a proactive message or how else could I trigger a proactive message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In addition to the standard *api/messages/* endpoint, you will need *api/notify* endpoint and trigger the proactive turn.

Here is a sample bot with a messages endpoint, and an additional notify endpoint that is used to send proactive messages to the user.

[image]

Here is a C# .NET Core [proactive message sample project](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)

Check out [BotBuilder-Samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) for more samples.